# How To Create Business Card Product In magento?

Tags: magento, product

i want to create product which name business card which contains

Size , Quantity, Name on Card and Image i do with custom option but i want 
to know how the it will appear in admin panel.

For example, 
if i upload the image in product front end then where is appear in admin panel

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new product with type = Virtual Product and any attribute set
2. Assign on this product some custom options. You also can create custom option: input with type file.
3. Purchase this test product and you will see inside order all necessary data.

Comment: Hello zhartaunik i didn't understand what you want to say